# How can my Azure App Services use more outbound IP addresses?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

My collection of app services in Azure have several web jobs that run behind-the-scenes and consume an external, third-party api via the web. This third-party api throttles me by my IP address. As my app is growing, I am scaling out and even separating modules out into separate app services. However, even with separate app services, each app service and scale out instance uses the same set of outbound IP addresses. So no matter how much I scale out, I am still throttled the same by this external api. I am getting more and more customers, and I am starting to get more and more timeouts from this external api. Is there a way to configure each of my app services to use a different set of outbound IPs? Or, am I able to have more than 4 separate outbound IP addresses assigned to an app service?

Comment: I believe each Azure data center has it's own set of outbound IP addresses, so if you were to have your app service run in different regions (if that works for you), then it's likely each region would have a different set of outbound IPs.